# Sets closed under a (restricted) function

Tags: functions

Imagine I have a function of the form $f: A \times B \rightarrow C$.  I then have the following sets:

\begin{eqnarray}
S_1 &=& \{a_1, b_1, c_1\}, \ \mathrm{where}\ f(a_1, b_1) = c_1 \\
S_2 &=& \{a_2, b_2, c_2\}, \ \mathrm{where}\ f(a_2, b_2) = c_2 \\
&\vdots& \\
S_n &=& \{a_n, b_n, c_n\}, \ \mathrm{where}\ f(a_n, b_n) = c_n \\
\end{eqnarray}

The function $f$ knows nothing about the $S_i$; however, when $f$ is applied to the elements of a given set, it yields a result in that same set (kind of like an internal operation of $S_i \times S_i \rightarrow S_i)$.  This seems to be some sort of function restriction (almost $f\vert_{S_i}$), but it would almost have to be expressed like:

\begin{equation}
f\vert_{S_i \times S_i \rightarrow S_i}(a_i, b_i) = c_i
\end{equation}

Is there a better way to express this type of situation?  Could we say that the $S_i$ are closed under the operation $f$?